# Angular multiple routing parameters

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In my angular 4 application I need to go in the same page with different routing param, for example I have:

1. `/ticketBundles/{id}`
2. `/ticketBundles/new`
3. `/ticketBundles/{id}/copy`

Now when I am navigating I use `this.router.navigate(path,id)`
In 2 and 3 I need to go in the same page but in a different "mode", In third case I need to load some data so what is the best practice to do that?
Third path is a good path?
If I use a path like `/ticketBundles/copy/{id}` I am following a good way?

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to follow RESTFUL programming. [What exactly is RESTful programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming)

So for example the closest you can get in your example would be..:

```
NEW (POST): /ticketBundle 
UPDATE (PUT): /ticketBundle/{id}
SHOW (GET): /ticketBundle/{id}
```

and for your copy i would do `/ticketBundle/{id}/copy`

You should take a look at the official docs for angular routing to help you 1. Navigate to a new page. 2. Pass in the params. 3. Retrieve the params on a new page.

https://angular.io/guide/router

In your routing module:

```
{ path: 'ticketBundle/:id', component: ticketComponent }
```

In your component

```
  this.router.navigate(['/ticketBundle', { id: ticketID}]);
```

Comment: following `/ticketBundle/{id}/copy` how can I manage routing when I route to, and how to set code in my component

Comment: ok and in the `/ticketBundle/{id}/copy` routes how ca I manage it, I don't want to use query params because the path will be `/ticketBundle;id={id};mode=copy`

Comment: Why not use params? /ticketBundle/{id}/{mode}. This way you can check the mode param and depending on what it is such as copy, then carry out those functions